# How did Akemi knew that Shiho will visit that house and find the cassettes?

Tags: detective-conan

In Detective Conan episodes 340-341, case titled "Hidden Bathroom Secret", Miyano Akemi visits the house (which was lent by her father to her father's friend) and hides the cassette tapes (from her mother to her sister, Shiho) in the toilet sink.

I am curious how Akemi knew that in future Shiho will come to that house and find those cassettes?